# I don't get this task in Java Script

Tags: javascript

Please help me. I'm doing exercise and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong if all conditions execute. The task consists in returning the provided string with only  the first letter of each word capitalized. My code performs this condition, but It doesn't get me ahead.

```
function titleCase(str) {
 var text = str.toLowerCase();
 var arr = text.split(" ");
 var txt = " ";
 var i;
 for(i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
 txt += arr[i][0].toUpperCase() + arr[i].slice(1) + " " ;
}
 return txt;
}

titleCase("sHoRt AnD sToUt");
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't get you ahead? The code works fine.

Comment: Check the spaces in `txt`

Answer (score 1):

You are adding extra whitespace (`var txt = " "` should be `var text = ''`), try this instead:

```js
function titleCase(str) {
 var text = str.toLowerCase();
 
 // split on spaces, map over array and return capitalized word and join on space
 return text.split(' ').map((word) => {
    return word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
 }).join(' ');
}

alert(titleCase("sHoRt AnD sToUt"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to return the string back with the first letters capitalized, I can see one problem in your output. You should be returning

```
"Short And Stout"
```

but instead you return

```
" Short And Stout "
```

with a space before and after your string. You can fix this by initializing `txt` to an empty string rather than a space, and then either trimming the last space off at the end after your loop, or by only adding the space if you aren't on the last element of `arr`. That is:

```
var txt = "";
for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   txt += arr[i][0].toUpperCase() + arr[i].slice(1);
   if (i != arr.length - 1) txt += " ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression instead.

```
function titleCase(txt){
   return txt.toLowerCase().replace(/\b\w/g, function(m){return m.toUpperCase();});
}
console.log(titleCase("sHoRt AnD sToUt"));//"Short And Stout"
```

Some explanation.
`//` regular expression (RegEx), `g` for global (else first only)
`\b` word boundary
`\w` any word symbol a-z (plus _)
`m` (function parameter) is match in the string